Why is verify user email by email link using firebase failing?
in my app the user logged in using phone number auth from firebase , after logged he can add his email from profile fragment , i want to verify this email by sending email link from firebase but the problem always Failed to send the email, i dont know why
this is my code
btn.setOnClickListener {
            firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "is Success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "is Failure!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }

and i have enable email link and Email/Password auth in firebase , What could be the problem?

What do you mean by "he can add his email from the profile fragment"? In which place are you updating the email? In the FirebaseUser object?

The sendEmailVerification method returns a Task. When a task fails, it contains an exception with details on the root cause of that failure. If you log the exception, you can find out what went wrong.
  ...
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
  ...
}

My first guess is that you're hitting rate limits by repeated testing btw, but the details of the exception will confirm (or deny) that.
